How to create data frame using gz file in Azure data bricks?
I want to create one data frame using gz file in Azure Data bricks environment.
Help me how to create data frame
my file looks like: test_20240423.gz
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:/mnt/datascience/information-mart/Internal/CTR/Product/BASE_CTR_DEAL_DIM/test_20240423.gz")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_test");


do you get error message when you run it? Show it in question (not in comments).

Reading gzipped parquet files from spark - Stack Overflow

@dasa m, Can you provide any error if you got? what is the output that the above code gave?

You are attempting to read a gzip file into a data frame without unzipping it, which might be the reason you cannot create the data frame. You can follow the format below to create a data frame using a gzip file in Azure Databricks:
Unzip the gzip file using the following code:
import gzip
import shutil

input_path = '/dbfs/<filePath>/test.gzip'
output_path = '/dbfs/<filePath>/test.parquet'  

# Decompress the gzip file
with gzip.open(input_path, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

print(f'File decompressed and saved to: {output_path}')

It will successfully unzip the file into the mentioned path. You can find it using dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/<filePath>/') as shown below:

Read that unzipped parquet file into a data frame using the following code:
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("dbfs:/FileStore/<filePath>/test.parquet")
display(df) 

It will successfully read the file into a data frame as shown below:

